# Correct way to instrument OpenTelemetry HttpClient on a web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, open-telemetry

I have a Razor web app (.NET 8) client I want to get metrics for execution and calls to other APIs

I have the following nuget pkgs installed:

- OpenTelemetry
- OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console
- OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore
- OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http

In Program.Main I configure it

```
TracerProvider tracer = null;

try
{
    ...
    app.MapRazorPages();
    // using ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault has no effect, nor does moving init to top
    tracer = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateEmpty())
                .AddSource("test")
                .AddConsoleExporter()
                .Build();

    app.Run();
}
finally
{
    tracer?.Dispose();
}
```

I have a service where I need to call an API I'd like get trace for.  Using static `ActivitySource` for now, but the goal is to create one (or few) for my application and re-use (not one per class)

```
class MyService : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly ActivitySource _source1= new ActivitySource("test");

    async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyMethod()
    {
        using var activity1 = _source1.StartActivity("action");
        var source2 = new ActivitySource("test");
        using var activity2 = source2.StartActivity("action");
        ...
    }

    void Dispose()
    {
        _source1?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I am seeing

1. `_source1` doesn't have any listener and `activity1` is null
2. `source2` has a listener, and `activity2` is a valid object

I am trying to construct only one ActivitySource per best practice, but it's not working.  What am I doing wrong or missing in my setup?

**UPDATE:**
The problem turned out doing `builder.Services.AddScoped<MyService>` causes the service to be constructed when the page is first rendered, and dispose is invoked after render. When I click on button to trigger action, it gets constructed again, but ActivitySource doesn't get reconstructed.

Will need to better understand `AddScoped`, but switching to `AddSingleton` works for my purpose now

Comment: You don't have to do anything beyond `AddHttpClientInstrumentation`. HttpClient already uses ActivitySource/Activity. I suspect the real question is how to design your Traces and Spans. It's NOT a best practice to have just one ActivitySource per class or application. ActivitySource maps to Traces and Activity to Spans below it. The ActivitySources you need depend on how you want to monitor your application\

Comment: I strongly suggest creating a .NET Aspire Starter project and start experimenting with activities while looking at the logs and traces in the Dashboard. You'll soon find you only really need a *few* ActivitySources, depending on what you consider a boundary in a project (subsystems? Services?). You definitely *don't* want one ActivitySource per class because the trace viewer becomes unreadable

Comment: I am not planning to use one ActivitySource (AS) per class, Trying to first figure out how to get a static AS working so I can reuse it (as per msft best practice https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-instrumentation-walkthroughs#best-practices-1).  Additionally I'd like to be able to use the `Activity.Current.TraceId` in my client and api/service logs so I can also correlate the log events

Comment: That's why I'm telling you to create a .NET Aspire Starter template. It contains two separate services *and* the exact configuration you want in a separate `Defaults` project. Not only do you get the code you want, you get to actually see how your choices affect your traces.

Comment: As for `use the Activity.Current.TraceId in my client` that's also handled automatically *but* the real trick is passing the traceid from one service to another. This can be done with a bit of configuration, in which case HttpClient will send the trace Id to remote services

Answer (score 1):

A few comments around your solution.

Based on your example, it looks like we are dealing with an ASP.NET Core project (due to the `app.MapRazorPages()` stuff). Given that, I'd strongly recommend leveraging [the `OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting` package](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting) instead of manually handling the SDK creation.

Secondly, instead of using `ResourceBuilder.CreateEmpty()` it is best to do `ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()`, but again, that is also taken care of by Hosting extensions and you don't need to add it. I would however recommend adding at least some service information with `AddService()` on the `ResourceBuilder`.

Thirdly, it appears that you need to have the `ActivitySource` in place before you call `AddSource`, otherwise [OTEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Native_Computing_Foundation#OpenTelemetry) will not be able to find your activity source. This explains why you switching to a singleton works (I assume you were passing in a pre-created instance, which is what triggers the static field to be newed up and thus become available for OTEL to pick it up).

Try something like this:

```cs
    builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .ConfigureResource(c => c.AddService("YourServiceNameHere"))
        .WithTracing(c => c
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
            .AddSource("test")
            .AddConsoleExporter();

    ...
    app.MapRazorPages();

    app.Run();
```

For the `ActivitySource`, Microsoft defines a few best practices in their main article here:

- [Adding distributed tracing instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-instrumentation-walkthroughs)

> Create the ActivitySource once, store it in a static variable and use that instance as long as needed. Each library or library subcomponent can (and often should) create its own source.

You are already using a `static` field to store your source, but it is inside a class that is only instantiated later in the flow. Instead, consider moving the `ActivitySource` initialization to the beginning of the app itself and then pass it along (you can even use [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) if you want).